# UPDATE SELECT en base al valor maximo de una columna en otra tabla MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una 2 tablas las cuales contienen múltiples columnas, el sistema de personajes tiene 5 index relacionados al ID de cuenta, lo que deseo hacer es obtener el characters.points más alto entre los 5 posibles ID de characters asociados a TODAS las ID de cuentas, y almacenar esto en accounts.points.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Obtener characters.points más alto DONDE idaccount = x <- (valor dinamico, debería buclearse para hacerse en todos los index) y almacenar ese valor máximo en accounts.points donde 'id' sea dicha X

Comment: oky que tienes del código ??? tienes tambien el esquema de las dos base de datos???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la forma, creé 2 Stored procedures, uno para buclear el otro:

`charpoints_to_accpoints

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE puntos INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET puntos = (SELECT MAX(c.Points) AS maxpoints FROM characters c WHERE c.idPlayer = value);
    
    IF (puntos > 0) THEN
    UPDATE players p SET p.points = puntos  WHERE p.id = value;
END
```

### `

`charpoints_to_accpointsALL

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE a INT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT a.id FROM players a;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    
    OPEN cur1;
    
    read_loop:LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO a;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        CALL charpoints_to_accpoints(a);
    END LOOP;
    
    CLOSE cur1;
END
```

`
Esto ejecutaría el código en todos los index a